# What type of relay do I need?

Tags: electrical

[image]

This is the relay I need to replace.  I have the part number so can find it however I’m wondering if this is just a generic item and if so what is it called.

I can see it is a 4 pin 12volt 20amp relay however as I google this I get other names with differing diagrams which maybe important.

Is there a generic name for this relay and if so what term should I search for?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In layman's terms it's called a *relay*. This is a generic relay. You can find it easily on the interwebz if you do a Google search for [Hyundai Motor Company Relay 95224-29750](https://t.ly/Atap). You'll be able to find it *very easily*.

Comment: Paul you missed the point.  I want to know what the replacement relay is without brand or product number.  Since it’s a generic relay I should be able to get it anywhere?  For example do I search ‘4 pin 12v 20 amp relay’ and just get one of those?  Problem is they come up with different diagrams on it not sure what it is exactly.

Comment: @JamesWilson - My answer is valid. If you do the search, you'll find all sorts of *generic* replacements for the relay. Search engines are very good for showing alternatives to the specific thing you are looking for ... which is the case in point.